# Git branch name tab completion from non-prefix substring

Tags: bash, git, autocomplete

Git completion scripts allow you to tab complete names of branches from the command line. I would like to be able to tab complete based on any substring in the branch name.

Example branches:

```
TS-45673-great-branch
TS-45691-lesser-branch
```

To use tab completion currently to get to `TS-45673-great-branch` uniquely requires typing `TS-4567<tab><tab>`

I'd like to be able to type `gre<tab><tab>`.

Is there a way to do this today?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if you have found a better solution. I have a small hack. My new company also wants to follow similar branch convention. (Technically, local branches shouldn't be a concern, but when pushing it for PR, it is convenient if we follow the same pattern for local branch)

This is the hack I did.
First find a way to get the list of branches you want. For example,

```
git branch | cut -c3- | egrep "^TS-[[:digit:]]+-$cur"
```

On the git-completion script, for example, if you used this script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/contrib/completion/git-completion.bash
go to the `__git_refs ()`

Within that method, just add this line somewhere at the top. (I couldn't find the ideal place, so added it at the top it worked. Any line that is printed would be treated as an autocompletion option. even `echo hello` would treat hello as an option.

---

If you want to find where the git completion script is located,

```
$ complete -p git
complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap__git_main git
```

Then `__git_wrap__git_main` is the command.

```
# Turn on extended shell debugging
shopt -s extdebug

# Dump the source file and other details
declare -F __git_wrap__git_main

# Turn off extended shell debugging
shopt -u extdebug
```

Note:

1. This is not perfect, but works for now. In some cases, things works wierdly. For example, if you had another `greater_branch`, then typing `gre` and tab, would print all three branches, and the prefix common to all three will only (TS-1) be filled in.
2. instead of `egrep "^TS-[[:digit:]]+-$cur"`, just adding egrep `"^TS-[[:digit:]]+-.*$cur"` would add a better substring search. Or even,

```
local pattern=`echo $cur | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1.*/g'` 
git branch | cut -c3- | egrep "^TS-[[:digit:]]+-$pattern"
```